# Is it possible to use "hashFiles" in the definition of an environment variable?

Tags: github-actions

The `hashFiles` function is helpful when caching dependencies in GitHub Actions. It's often used like this:

```yaml
- uses: actions/cache@v3
  with:
  path: |
    path/to/dependencies
    some/other/dependencies
  key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
```

Is it possible to use `hashFiles` in the definition of an environment variable? i.e. like this:

```yaml
env:
  HASH_YARN_LOCK: "hashFiles('**/yarn.lock')"
  ...

- uses: actions/cache@v3
  with:
  path: |
    path/to/dependencies
    some/other/dependencies
  key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ env.HASH_YARN_LOCK }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [contexts documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability) includes, as well as which *contexts* are accessible within each workflow key, which *special functions* are available to them:

> In addition, some functions may only be used in certain places. For example, the `hashFiles` function is not available everywhere.
>
> ...
>
> | Workflow key | Context | Special functions |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `env` | `github`, `secrets`, `inputs`, `vars` | None |

As you can see, `hashFiles` isn't exposed.

When you think about *when* that `env` object key is being evaluated, this is inevitable - that value needs to be determined at a point before `actions/checkout` or similar could possibly have been run, so there are no files in the workspace to hash.